# overflow-y auto strange behavior: when scrollbar is visible, it sometimes causes content to shrink, and sometimes not

Tags: css, overflow, reflow

I'm trying to show the list of errors to the user inside absolute positioned DIV. Sometimes there will be only a few of these errors, but sometimes there could be tens of them. I want to keep the DIV as small as possible (both width and height), but when the height exceeds some predefined value, scrollbar should appear.

Unfortunately, when using `overflow-y: auto`, showing the scrollbar makes the error lines to wrap, because they were using as much width as possible, and I'd like to avoid this wrapping.

I have created [JS fiddle to simulate this issue](https://jsfiddle.net/tissaya/483au0kd/8/) with minimal code, but to my surprise, I noticed that while refreshing the fiddle page shows the result with wrapped text that I want to avoid (let's name it *result 1*), clicking **Run** works differently - it looks like container DIV is expanded and scrollbar doesn't cause contents to reflow (*result 2*)... The same happens when page is reloaded, and then result pane is resized. I have no idea why it works like this, and would gladly find this out.

I reproduced the snippet below, and I see that running it shows the result 1, but reloading the snippet frame (e.g. right click and 'Reload frame' in Chrome), display result 2.

Any ideas why, and what can I do to achieve result 2 consistently?

Btw - button was added for some testing, but is not really relevant...

Thanks!

```js
$('#b1').click(function() { $('.o2').toggleClass('hiddenScroll'); });
```

```css
.o {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.hiddenScroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.o1 {
    top: 40px;
}

.o2 {
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='b1'>toggle scroll</button>

<div class='o o1'>
    <div>aaa bbb ccc ddd eee</div>
    <div>aaa bbb ccc ddd eee</div>
</div>

<div class='o o2'>
    <div>aaa bbb ccc ddd eee</div>
    <div>aaa bbb ccc ddd eee</div>
    <div>aaa bbb ccc ddd eee</div>
    <div>aaa bbb ccc ddd eee</div>
</div>
```